# How to change the array uniformly

Tags: php

here is my array

```
$myarray= array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

I just want to multiply it by 5 times and dispay the answer as

```
5
10
15
20
```

how can i do this operation using the foreach loop

Comment: These are the basics, please read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP needs to do it using `foreach`

It was as simple like you should Iterate inside the array using a `foreach` and `multiply * 5` and have a `<br>` like this

```
<?php
$myarray = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($myarray as $value) 
{
    echo ($value*5).'<br>';
}
?>
```

Here's the [Eval](https://eval.in/373356)